# Why am I getting Error while updating the flutter sdk?

Tags: flutter

> Waiting for 0 seconds, press CTRL+C to quit ... Checking Dart SDK
>   version... 'PowerShell.exe' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file. Error: Unable to
>   update Dart SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Type these commands in your terminal:

```
flutter channel stable
```

```
flutter upgrade
```

Visit https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Hotfixes-to-the-Stable-Channel